# Modifying a clone of a list (python)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have 2 lists :

```
l1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
l2 = list(l1)
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) post if I modify `l2`, `l1` should not change.

But if I do the following:

```
del l2[1][1]
```

`l1` will be modified as well.

Is this intended and how can I prevent it from happening?
I also noticed that the ids of `l1[1]` and `l2[1]` are the same.

Comment: Think of the lists as treasure maps. Your `l1` has three treasures marked on it, and you copied the map on a different paper (`l2`). Any lines you draw on your new treasure map won't affect the old one. However, if you take one treasure off, and both maps will lose one of their treasures (sure it's still visible on the map, but you get the idea). The maps are different, but the treasures are the same. This same applies to your Python lists; the elements are still the same, but removing or adding more elements to one list wont do the same to the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list(l1)` will make a *shallow copy* of `l1`; that is, all references inside the list `l1` will be copied to the new list. Modifications to these nested lists will be visible in the original list since you modify objects with the same reference.

Take a look at the matching `id`s for the lists:

```
print("l1 object references: ", *map(id, l1))
l1 object references:  139927285488584 139927284661256 139927284723784

print("l2 object references: ", *map(id, l2))
l2 object references:  139927285488584 139927284661256 139927284723784
```

If you didn't have lists in lists, this wouldn't be an issue:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = list(l1)    
del l2[1]    
print(l1)  # [1, 2, 3]
print(l2)  # [1, 3]
```

The solution is, instead of using `list`, use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy

l1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
l2 = copy.deepcopy(l1)
del l2[1][1]
print(l1)  # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Now the `id`s of the nested lists are different and mutating one leaves the other alone:

```
print("l1 object references: ", *map(id, l1))
l1 object references:  139927284726984 139927284737160 139927284737800

print("l2 object references: ", *map(id, l2))
l2 object references:  139927284710216 139927285123976 139927284678344
```

Of course, a list comprehension where `list` is called on every element also suffices in achieving the same effect :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a list of lists. If instead you write:

```
l2 = [list(li) for li in l1]
```

You will be able to delete or modify elements of `l2` without changing `l1`. This is because, when one has a list of lists, `l2 = list(l1)` creates a copy of the outer list, but the inner lists of `l2` are still references to the original inner lists of `l1`. So, if you change elements in the inner lists of `l2`, these changes will be reflected in the original inner lists in `l1`. If you create explicit copies of the inner lists of `l1`, as I did above, you avoid this problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
l2 = [i[:] for i in l1]
```

This works because you need to actually copy the inner lists by value, not the outer one, in order for them to be completely seperate.

Here is an example on how this works:

```
l1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
l2 = [i[:] for i in l1]
l2[0][0]=3
print (l2) #[[3, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print (l1) #[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```